# SSIS, create file excel with Getdate()

Tags: excel, visual-studio, ssis

i want to create an excel file with File System Task in ssis and that in the new excel file be saved with the current date

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable and create an expression to build out the file name like this (or change it to be in any format you want it in):

```
"FileName_" +    (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(GETDATE()) + "" +
    RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(GETDATE()), 2) + "" +
    RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY( GETDATE()), 2) + 
"_" + Right("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252) DatePart("hh",getdate()),2) +
Right("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252) DatePart("mi",getdate()),2) + ".xlsx"
```

Will create a file name like this:
FileName_20230510_0755.xlsx

Comment: What are the empty strings for?

Comment: Not needed, I think I had underscores in there at one time and just left the empty quotes in case I wanted to put them back it would be easy.  So filename would have 2023_05_10_0755  as the filename, but not required and can be removed.